# Don't understand why Backbone collection.create doesnt POST an array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying out Backbone and have hit a bit of a problem.

If I use Collection.create with an array of models then the JSON posted to the server doesnt appear to be very easy to parse.

Example:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on( 'all', function(e)
                { console.log( "Person model all " + this.get("name") + ", event: " + e ); }
            );
    }
});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on( 'all', function(e) { console.log( "People collection event: " + e ); } );
    },
    url: "/models/",
    model: Person
});

var people = new People();
people.create( [ { "name":"joe", "age":24 }, { "name":"dan", "age":42 } ] );
```

My server then receives the following JSON:

```
{"0":{"name":"joe","age":24},"1":{"name":"dan","age":42}}
```

What is this and why isnt it a simple array like:

```
[{"name":"joe","age":24},{"name":"dan","age":42}]
```

As it is, its very hard to parse because what makes things worse is if you do a Model.save() then you get a simple object (more valid) without those ID values.

The only way I have been able to parse this collection post is to do something like:

```
for( var n in payloadobj )
{
    var person = new Object();
    person.id = parseInt(n, 10);
    person.name = payloadobj[n].name;
    person.age = payloadobj[n].age;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is, am I missing something, am I going to override some stuff just to make it more consistent or shall i just avoid Collection.create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections in Backbone use arrays internally, but are intended to conveniently provide access to ordered and unordered models. So, when you add People instances without IDs, they're automatically being assigned a cid (clientId) property (as you haven't provided an alternative id).

However, in the case you present, your code is calling the `Create` method, which takes only one model at a time (not an array). So, it's creating the wrong structure internally. You could do this:

```
var people = new People([{ "name": "joe", "age": 24 }, { "name": "dan", "age": 42}]);
```

The `create` method is just a convenience method that parses a single model (and looks for a `cid`/`id`) on each model (prefixed with a 'c').

So, if you write your own save function, you can just call `toJSON` on the people collection and you'll get what you want (an array of Person objects).

Comment: It is still very strange that it posts this strange construction to the server in this way as a) the server does not care about the internal ID that Backbone has used and b) to prove (a), when you just create one model at a time then it does not post the cid and it posts a proper JSON object ... I think creating multiple objects in the one 'create' should be avoided

Comment: Yes -- I realized that I'd misread your code (the call to 'Create' in particular). So, Backbone was creating an internal structure that was completely not what you wanted (it was still creating a CID, but it wasn't really creating a Person object at all). I've fixed my answer.